# Pass arguments through pipe to external command with system one after another

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to open a external command from Perl using system call. I am working on Windows. How can I pass arguments to it one after another?

For example:

```
system("ex1.exe","arg1",arg2",....);
```

Here `ex1.exe` is external command and i would like it to process arg1 first and then arg2 and so on...

I would appreciate for your reply,

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Are you trying to pass multiple arguments to the system command? because what you have is correct to do that. If you want to pass one argument at a time then you need to use a loop

Comment: yeah i tried using it... my ex1.exe is a C++ console application if i try system ("ex1.exe" , "arg1", "arg2"....) it reads in all commands at once on its command prompt consider ex1.exe as some application where i need to type in arg1 first press enter then on the same console type arg2 and press enter and so on –

Comment: @Cfreak: he wants to pipe data to `ex1.exe`'s STDIN. I think.

Comment: If you are more specific about the exact command and arguments, you will get a better answer. I don't know if you have one command with several arguments several commands with several arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [pipe open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

{
    local ++$|;

    open my $EX1_PIPE, '|-', 'ex1.exe' 
        or die $!;

    print $EX1_PIPE "$_\n"
        for qw/arg1 arg2 arg3/;

    close $EX1_PIPE or die $!;
}
```

I'm assuming you want to pipe data to `ex1.exe`'s STDIN; for example, if `ex1.exe` is the following perl script:

```
print while <>;
```

Then if you run the above code your output should be:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

Comment: Hi Pedro... Thank you so much. Last question :) what if my arguments are commands to ex1.exe like arg1= config file.ini; arg2 = log test.txt; arg3 = run test .... and so on should i store all of them in an array and then use that array instead...

Comment: Yeah, just store them all in an array: `@args = ("config file.ini", "log test.txt", "run test", ...)`, and do `print $EX1_PIPE $_ for @args`.

Comment: thanks Pedro.... but after executing first command from the array teh script goes mad and i get >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> all over my console window ????

Comment: ok if i want to pass enter key also with each argument what would be the argument to pass to ex1.exe....

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was a typo on my part. I fixed it, I guess you saw it.

Comment: thanks a lot Pedro... Also what if I want to open 2 or 3 .exe's at once.. for example ex1.exe ex2.exe ex3.exe and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to execute ex1.exe once for each argument?  Something similar to:

```
> ex1.exe arg1
> ex1.exe arg2
> ex1.exe arg3
```

If so, you would do:

```
for my $arg (@args)
{
   system( 'ex1.exe', $arg);
}
```